# Is there a difference between initializing at declare and assigning after declare

Tags: typescript

Here's the code :

[Initialized ver.]

```
interface ContactList {
  group?: string,
  list?: {
    name: string,
    tel: string
  }[]
}

const myList: ContactList = {
  group: 'Friends',
  list: [{
    name: 'James',
    tel: '1234-5678'
  }]
}
```

[Assigned ver.]

```
interface ContactList {
  group?: string,
  list?: {
    name: string,
    tel: string
  }[]
}

const myList: ContactList = {
  group: 'Friends',
}

myList.list = [{
  name: 'James',
  tel: '1234-5678'
}]
```

It is almost same, but after that code, typescript compiler throws an error only for [Initialized ver.] on below codes :

```
myList.list.push({name: 'Amy', tel: '2345-6789'});
// cause an error : Object is possibly 'undefined' (not cause an error for [Assign ver.])
```

I think it's typescript compiler bug, or am I wrong for understanding of typescript behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is, that in the first case you state the type, while in the second case it is inferred by the control flow.

That means the in the first example the compiler just checks that what you assign to `myList` is assignable to `ContactList` and assumes it to be a `ContactList` afterwards while in the second case it infers a different type at the point where you assign the `list` property in which `list` isn't optional.

If you change the first initialization version to this:

```
interface ContactList {
  group?: string,
  list?: {
    name: string,
    tel: string
  }[]
}

const myList = {
  group: 'Friends',
  list: [{
    name: 'James',
    tel: '1234-5678'
  }]
}

myList.list.push({name: 'Amy', tel: '2345-6789'});
```

The error isn't present anymore, although I understand that you want to state it there to have an error at that line in case the initialization is wrong.

Comment: Although I state the type in the first case, TS compiler can recognize myList.list is no more undefined and has value like second case. So I thought if the compiler is smarter, do not throw an error on first case.

If TS throws an error for the possibility of delete for myList.list, the possibility also could be applied to second case that assigned directly to myList.list.

Comment: It is not about the possibility to delete the prop. It is just about the way the compiler follows your code. It is true that it would be nice if the compiler would be smarter here, but this is how it works currently. - I rephrased the second paragraph of the answer to hopefully explain better what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, this is how it works currently.
Thank for your comment for behavior of TS compiler, it helps me. :)